# Are there word problems without an evident unknown?

Tags: education, word-problem

I teach secondary school maths. I appreciate the expressive precision in which word problems are couched. The unknown is usually stated in question tags at the end. 
I want to know if this is always the case? Are there no occasions where the authors or mathematician is not precise in expressing himself such that the unknown is explicitly ambiguous? If yes, then is there any algorithm or method by which one can resolve the unknown i.e find out what the unknown is before undertaking to get an equation and then solve the problem?

Comment: The problem here is that a problem is a product of the person that makes it, it's not even a matter of having convention differences, they're just all different based on who is writing them. This means there's no real catch-all, definitive answer.

Comment: This is what word problems are all about: You are thrown into a "mathematical situation", and using your head you have to find out what's going on here.

Comment: Doesn't a (word) problem have to pose a question?  Setting up the word problem means identifying the unknown needed to be found and working out the (algebraic or otherwise) equations that allow that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to start by asking yourself "what quantity or quantities do I need to know in this problem?"  That gives you your main variable or variables.  Then you want to see how to express all the
given data in terms of the unknown(s) --- this may require introducing additional variables.

Comment: Thanks Roberts. I think (POV) that not all problems would have the same expressive precision as the textbooks. Could there be an algorithmic method of stating the unknown if the question was not phrased with the expressive precision of textbooks?

Comment: I don't know what "expressive precision" you're referring to.  I certainly haven't seen the same textbooks you have.  And do you seriously mean an algorithm? 
An "algorithm to state the unknown" would have to start with algorithms for parsing natural language and extracting the semantic content.  It might also need to contain a great deal of knowledge about the subject matter.  These are the sorts of things that are easy for humans but very hard for machines.